# Intellij - commiting log for SVN clears on error - any way to restore log?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

On commiting log and forget update branch - I get **dialog with error** due one file was outdated and I need uptodate it first.

All text what I've wrote in log field clears and I am not able to restore it. This annoying situation makes me do the same thing which I did few seconds ago... 
Can I somehow restore my text instead watching the previous (there should be text what I wrote..)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a button for opening a history of messages, sometimes what you wrote last time is not displayed, but it is in the history.
[image]